# jquery on click event doesn't work when using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am doing an ajax to pull information from a spreadsheet on my google drive, and then using the following code to display them in HTML:

I have this HTML:

```
        <section class="p-booking" id="booking">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="event-box">
                        <!-- caixas puxados do drive -->
                    </div>
                </div>
        </section>
```

And this JS:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {


var caixasEvento = [];
caixasEvento.push('<div class="col-md-3">');
caixasEvento.push('<div data-id="' + something + '" class="box">');
caixasEvento.push('<h1 class="day">' + something + '</h1>');
caixasEvento.push('<h1 class="local">' + something + '</h1>');
caixasEvento.push('<img class="local-img" src="' + image + '">');
caixasEvento.push('</div>');
caixasEvento.push('</div>');
$('.event-box').append(caixasEvento.join(''));
});
```

And then I need an alert every time someone clicks the box:

```
$('.box').on('click', function() {
    alert('test')
});
```

I'm using a script link tag in the bottom of my html document.

the box is normally appearing with all the drive information.

It does not work. I believe that is a problem related to the ajax, because if I create a div with the 'box' class, the alert works.

Comment: I do not see any ajax in your code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this is happening because the box element doesn't exist on the page when you try to setup the listener. Try this:

```
$('.event-box').on('click', '.box', function() {
  // do stuff here
});
```

Comment: @Dri Can you provide more of the original code? It's a little hard to tell what the problem is from what you provided. The order of execution may be important here.

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped. FWIW, I did try your sample with my solution and I was able to get the alert to display.

Comment: I do not know what happened. I wrote the code again and it worked haha.. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('.box').each(function()
 {
     $(this).click(clickHandler);
 });


 function clickhandler()
 {
      alert('test')
  }
```